# Model::loadMultiple doesn't fill models

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to create multiple records at once.

I have model ***Menu*** with following validate rules.

```
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['productID'], 'required'],
            [['userID', 'productID', 'portions'], 'integer'],
            [['userID'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }
```

In the controller, I have following code:

```
    public function actionCreate(){

    $products = Product::find()->where(['status'=>Product::STATUS_ACTIVE])->all();
    $models = [];
    foreach($products as $product){
        $models[] = new Menu;
    }


    if (Model::loadMultiple($models, Yii::$app->request->post()) && Model::validateMultiple($models)) {
        foreach( $models as $model ){
            $model->save(false);
        }
        $this->redirect('/site');
    }

    foreach($products as $index => $product){
        $models[$index]->productID = $product->id;
    }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'models' => $models,
    ]);
}
```

In the view **create** I have following code:

```
<div>
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?php foreach($models as $index =>  $model) { ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, "[$index]portions")->label($model->product->name) ?>

<?php } ?>

<div>
    <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app','Save'),['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
</div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

var_dump(Yii::$app->request->post()) gives me following resolt.

```
array(2) { ["_csrf-frontend"]=> string(88) "D-vbF_6B7YWBFlH1JTTWEOTeQb0esZhSRN7Bti0S-QdDm-0jj7Wd3dBUGqZBW5J2nrAq-VbfoAQIkpGDXCOtMg==" ["Menu"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["portions"]=> string(4) "9999" } [1]=> array(1) { ["portions"]=> string(4) "5555" } } }
```

The data comes but the method **loadMultiple** doesn't fill the models.
I don't understand, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to add **hiddenInput** for ***productID*** field  in the form, the validation failed because of that.

```
    <?php foreach($models as $index => $model) { ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, "[$index]portions")->label($model->product->name) ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, "[$index]productID")->hiddenInput(['value' => $model->productID])->label(false);?>    
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Your answer will likely fix the issue, but may not be the best approach in some circumstances. Say the hidden field should not be something the user should be able to change then you don't likely need it as a hidden input, instead you should take it out of the `rules` and `validateMultiple` will skip over it. Or you can also pass an array of attributes that `validateMultiple` should ONLY validate. Hope this helps you/someone.